# Combine multiple request for a request and hit api only once in Angular 2

Tags: angular

One service is being called in multiple components at the same time. How can we avoid firing multiple api calls and wait till the api has finished and returns observable.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    private data: string;
    private _subject$: AsyncSubject<string[]> = new AsyncSubject<stirng[]>();
    private obs: Observable<any>;
    constructor() { }

 public currentData$(): Observable<string[]> {
   this.getData();
   return this._subject$.asObservable();
}

private getData() {
  this.http.get(this.url)
  .map((r) => r))
  .share()
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this._subject$.next(res);
    this._subject$.complete();
  });
}
```

Here currentData$() is being called by multiple components at the same time. How can I avoid multiple api calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    private data: string;
    private _subject$: AsyncSubject<string[]>;
    private obs: Observable<any>;
    constructor() { }

 public currentData$(): Observable<string[]> {
   if(!this._subject$) {
      this._subject$ = new AsyncSubject<stirng[]>();
      this.getData().subscribe(this._subject$);
   }

   return this._subject$;    
}

private getData() {
  return this.http.get(this.url).map((r) => r));
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Comment: How do you use this in your custom components?

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb, what do you mean? Can you post a question with details?

Comment: @Maximus Obviously you call `currentData$()` function in your component to get the data since it is the only public function. Is this function returning your data or do you have to subscribe to it in some way since you get returned an Observable. I am a complete beginner regarding the whole Observable thing and wonder how you "wait" for your data receiving it from the server. Can you please post a single line where you call this function?

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb, yes, it's called like this `SomeServiceInstance.currentData$()`. The trick here is `AsyncSubject`. It will make a request to the server and then preserve the value. When it gets another subscriber it will return this value. It works very much like a promise. Read more [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#asyncsubject)